# Character panel keeps going to all caps even after switching if off

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have found tons of answers on how to turn off the all caps on the Character Panel on Photoshop 2021 which is great but it keeps going back to it. I click it, turn it off and it turns itself back on. Also, never paid any attention to this but it also keeps saying French instead of English: USA which also keeps going back to that after I change it. How do I change it so it stays changed unless I want all caps or French?

Comment: Hmm.. French and all caps... maybe there's a secret Photoshop "Beret" mode `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your presets are skewed. This used to happen to me all the time. To check if I'm correct you should try to reset a textbook to the preset entries (like [this](https://photoshoptrainingchannel.com/tips/reset-character-panel/)).

In that case you can [reset all preferences](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/reset-photoshop-preferences/) which is probably your best bet, unless you have lots of things you saved, or reset your character preferences.

This is quite weird: you open a new photoshop session, without any documents and go to window > character. There you set your preferred options and restart photoshop. Your preferences should be saved.